# Adding empty rows to a multi index panel in python

Tags: python, pandas, panel, multi-index, extrapolation

[Add an empty row to MultiIndex DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49231190/add-an-empty-row-to-multiindex-dataframe)

I want to refer to this link. How could I add the column idx_2 and its content r_1, r_2, r_3  to the new added row 'bar'? I want to do a linear extrapolation after adding empty rows to my multi index panel.

Comment: A sample code to construct your dataframe with a few rows would definitely help illustrate what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.